# Angular.js: Error: Module 'MyApp' is not available

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, module

I would like to use [this plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/QCl1ZV/preview) locally on my machine. However, when I either run it with the local Python server or `http-server`, I keep getting the following Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due     to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either     misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure      that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

My **html file** looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script scr="main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.1/papaparse.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-file-upload/1.1.5/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>CSV</h1>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="append">
      Append to existing on drag & drop
    </div>
    <div class="drop-container" nv-file-drop nv-file-over uploader="uploader">
      <textarea ng-model="csv" placeholder="Enter your CSV here, or drag/drop a CSV file"></textarea>
    </div>

    <h1>D3 Flare JSON</h1>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="compact"> Compact
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="tags.parent" placeholder="parent tag">
      <input type="text" ng-model="tags.children" placeholder="children tag">
      <input type="text" ng-model="tags.leaf" placeholder="leaf tag">
      <input type="text" ng-model="tags.size" placeholder="size tag">
    </div>
    <textarea readonly ng-model="json"></textarea>
  </body>

</html>
```

And the **main.js** file looks like this:

```
CSV to D3 Flare JSON converter in AngularJSPreview Edit Code
index.html
main.js
main.css
main.js
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload'])

.factory('FlareJson', ['$q', function($q) {
  function updateTree(curr, arr, tags) {
    if ((arr.length || 0) < 2) {
      return;
    }

    if (!curr.hasOwnProperty(tags.children)) {
      curr[tags.children] = [];
    }

    var elem;    
    if (arr.length == 2) {
      elem = {};
      elem[tags.leaf] = arr[0];
      elem[tags.size] = arr[1];
      curr[tags.children].push(elem);
    } else {
      curr[tags.children].some(function(e) {
        if (e[tags.parent] == arr[0] || e[tags.leaf] == arr[0]) {
          elem = e;
          return true;
        }
      });
      if (!elem) {
        elem = {};
        elem[tags.parent] = arr[0];
        curr[tags.children].push(elem);
      }
      updateTree(elem, arr.slice(1), tags);
    }
  }

  function buildJson(csv, compact, tags) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var result = {};
    result[tags.parent] = 'flare';

    Papa.parse(csv, {
      header: false,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      complete: function(csvArray) {
        csvArray.data.forEach(function(line) {
          if (line.length) {
            updateTree(result, line, tags);
          }
        });
        if (compact) {
          deferred.resolve(JSON.stringify(result));
        } else {
          deferred.resolve(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        }
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return buildJson;
}])

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', 'FlareJson',
function($scope, FileUploader, FlareJson) {
  $scope.csv = "";
  $scope.compact = false;
  $scope.json = "";
  $scope.tags = {
    parent: 'skill',
    children: 'children',
    leaf: 'name',
    size: 'level'
  };

  $scope.uploader = new FileUploader();

  $scope.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        if ($scope.append) {
          $scope.csv += event.target.result;
        } else {
          $scope.csv = event.target.result;
        }
      });
    };
    reader.readAsText(fileItem._file);
  };

  function update() {
    FlareJson($scope.csv, $scope.compact, $scope.tags).then(function(json) {
      $scope.json = json;
    });
  }

  $scope.$watchGroup(['csv', 'compact'], update);
  $scope.$watchCollection('tags', update);
}]);
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I already searched for similar error messages, but nothing that I found could help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load your script file before angularjs file that's why you are getting this error.
So, Add your "main.js" file after "angular.js" file.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script scr="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I put the main.js script at the end of my script definitions, but I'm still getting the same error `Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: Roy.23, this was a problem as well and you were the first to answer, so, I'm accepting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're loading your `main.js` before you load Angular. Try putting your script at the end of the script definitions:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.1.1/papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-file-upload/1.1.5/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script scr="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried, but I'm still getting the same error... (?)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, solved! Turns out, that the following couple of first lines in `main.js` were causing the trouble:

```
CSV to D3 Flare JSON converter in AngularJSPreview Edit Code
index.html
main.js
main.css
main.js
```

I removed them from `main.js`, now it works - yuhuu! :)